# POCO::PostgreSQL retrieve JSON datatype

Tags: json, postgresql, poco-libraries

What is the best way to retrieve data from JSON field in PostgreSQL using POCO framework?

The only way I see is:

```
Poco::Data::RecordSet rs(session, sql);
rs.moveFirst();
string value = rs[0].convert<std::string>(); // get JSON as string
Poco::JSON::Parser parser;
parser.parse(value);
Poco::Dynamic::Var result = parser.result();
// now we can extract Object, Array and so on
```

Direct extract

```
Poco::JSON::Object object = os[0].extract<Poco::JSON::Object>()
```

throws *Can not convert [ERRFMT] to [ERRFMT]* exception.
Any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
Var result = parser.parse(value);
Object::Ptr object = result.extract<Object::Ptr>();
```